# Error with JavaScript Ajax Query and Smarty

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, smarty

I am trying to use an AJAX JSONP Query to read documents from a CouchDB I have hosted on Cloudant.

[This](http://tox.sinaiem.org/poll.php) is webpage. The following is relevant code section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "https://acharya.cloudant.com/toxtweet";
console.log(url);
function getCloudantData(url) {
        $.ajax({
          'url': url, 
          'dataType': 'jsonp'
        }, 
        function (data) { 
          $('#importeddata').text(data);
        });
}
</script>
```

However, when I put this script tag into that webpage, I just get a blank webpage and I don't know why. I'm not even calling the function and JSLint says that there is no syntax error.

**Template HTML File**

```
{extends file='toxtweet.tpl'}
{block name="head"}
   <link href="./styles/poll.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="Screen">
   <script type="text/javascript">
           var url = "https://acharya.cloudant.com/toxtweet";
           console.log(url);
       $(function(){
          $.ajax({
           'url': 'https://acharya.cloudant.com/toxtweet', 
           'dataType': 'jsonp', 
            success:function (data) { 
             $('#ing').text(data); 
          }});});
     </script>
 {/block}
 {block name="body"}
 <h2> Do you think this tweet is discussing drugs? </h2>
     <form class="poll" method="post" actions="">
     <p id="chosen-tweet"><p>
     <ul>
    {foreach $answers as $answer}
        <li>
            <label class="poll_active">
                <input type="radio" name={$answer} value="0">{$answer@key}
            </label>
        </li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
</form>
<div id="ing"></div>
 {/block}
 {debug}
```

Comment: https://acharya.cloudant/com/toxtweet gives me a timeout - that's what gives you a blank page.

Comment: Interesting. When I go to "https://acharya.cloudant.com/" from a browser, I get the JSON response "{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.0.2","cloudant_build":"850"}"

Comment: your [proxy](http://tox.sinaiem.org/scripts/proxy.js) script is supposed to be ran with [node.js](http://nodejs.org/),

Comment: When I go to "https://acharya.cloudant.com/toxtweet" I get "{"update_seq":"1470793-g1AAAADqeJzLYWBgYMlgTmGQS0lKzi9KdUhJMjTWyyrNSS3QS87JL01JzCvRy0styQGqY0pkSLL___9_VhID68yPIE2ycE2WuPQkOQDJpHqotvnOxNqVxwIkGRqAFFDrfpDeWbloeg3x6z0A0Qu2d-6KLAAe5U3k","db_name":"toxtweet","purge_seq":0,"other":{"data_size":14362238306},"doc_del_count":0,"doc_count":1191731,"disk_size":3869479336,"disk_format_version":5,"compact_running":false,"instance_start_time":"0"}"

Comment: well, acharya.cloudant/com/toxtweet ain't the same as acharya.cloudant.com/toxtweet :)

Comment: @extramaster Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: works fine with the corrected url - response:
/* CouchDB */jQuery17107921177483718328_1356187255725({"update_seq":"1470793-g1AAAADpeJzLYWBgYMlgTmGQS0lKzi9KdUhJMjTSyyrNSS3QS87JL01JzCvRy0styQGqY0pkSLL___9_VhID68yPIE2ycE2WuPQkOQDJpHqotvnOxNqVxwIkGRqAFFDrfpDeWblEWgnRegCiFWzt3BVZANgoTbg","db_name":"toxtweet","purge_seq":0,"other":{"data_size":14362238306},"doc_del_count":0,"doc_count":1191731,"disk_size":3832828328,"disk_format_version":5,"compact_running":false,"instance_start_time":"0"});

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Sorry that's at typo. However, that's not what caused the error. (It persists even if I change it. For example, reload the webpage.)

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Then, why is http://tox.sinaiem.org/poll.php still blank?

Comment: after firing the ajax request once I now get http 500 when calling http://tox.sinaiem.org/poll.php - I doubt it's a javascript issue ;)

Comment: @mac389 node.js is a server software that uses JavaScript as it's primarily scripting language. Code that relies on node.js cannot be directly embedded into a webpage since the implementation of JavaScript between a browser and node.js are different.

Comment: Currently i am getting a `500 Internal Server Error` in the console on the ***http://tox.sinaiem.org/poll.php*** page

Comment: Yes, whenever I put the script tag in I get an error. The HTML code is involved because it's generated with Smarty and so there's a few PHP and TPL files. I thought that because the error appeared only after I started adding JavaScript that the error was in JS and not something deeper. :-/

Answer (score 3):

There is no version of [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that supports a second argument as a callback.. (*that syntax is just for the [shorthand versions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) like `$.get()`, `$.post()`, `$.getJSON` ..*)

Also note that you are using jquery methods, and if you have not loaded jquery before this snippet, it will stop javascript execution if `$` is not defined.

Use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCloudantData(url) {
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'https://acharya.cloudant.com/toxtweet', 
        'dataType': 'jsonp', 
        success:function (data) { 
            $('#importeddata').text(data); 
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: and  `$('#importeddata').text(data); ` does not make sense when data returned/requested is json . I hope that is just for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Yes, that is just to print it out for testing purposes. Of course, one wants to display processed versions of just a few fields from the JSON.